# Need help for putting 4 same divs into one css code (spacing)

Tags: html, css, margin

i dont know how to say (i think my english is not very good), but i need help for putting 4 same divs in to one css code.

**Problem:**

```
float:left; margin:10px 20px 10px 0;
```

As you can see at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Rwt/), tab number 2 and 4 does not fit to the space. There is free space at the right corner, but the max spacing is 20px.. is there even possible to fix this problem without jquery?

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers!

Comment: "There is free space at the right corner" what do you mean by this ? you are having free space because of margin

Comment: And that is the problem. I dont want that free space at the right corner :/

Comment: you mean free space between 1 and 2, 3 and 4 ?

Comment: i think you do not want the right margin of tab no 2 and 4 am i right?

Comment: Yes, i dont want margin of tab 2 and 4. Tabs should fit to the 100% without free space at the end of right corner :/

Comment: have a look at my answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your tabs css as mentioned below :

```
.tabs 
{ 
  float:left; 
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0; 
  width:50%; 
  height:100px; 
  background:grey; 
}
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Rwt/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Well, this does not work. I need two tabs in one line without free space at right corner :/

Comment: change width to **100%**. it will make all tabs in one column

Comment: Like i said: "two tabs in one line without free space at right corner". I am trying to fix this proble probably 5hrs~ :/

Comment: check my updated answer. added width to 50% and removed right margin. so tab 1-2 will be in same row without free space and same for tab 3-4

Comment: can you upload the picture of your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add last class with marign-right:0 !important;
my example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riazshah/A8Rwt/4/) and adjust width if it is helpful then ok otherwise let me know i will give you another technique

```
.tabs {float:left; margin:10px 20px 10px 0; width:48.5%; height:100px; background:grey; }
.last{ margin-right:0 !important;}
```

Comment: hmm, maybe you know, if there is possible to do this without including other css to class?